# How to find Indentured Servants in Buffalo, NY or Canada?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, new-york-state, canada, employment-records

I've tried the City Hall on my last trip to Buffalo with no luck. All I know is my great grandmother was given to a family as a young girl. She came to the USA sometime around **1880 to 1884**, and I believe married 1892-1895. Her husband was from Hamilton, Ontario, Canada.

Other than US Federal Census Records 1900,1920 & 1930 and cemetery records I've not been able to find any other documentation other than a US/Canadian boarder crossing record that might be her.

**Elizabeth GALLOWAY** (1 Sep 1868 born Scotland-19 Oct 1937 died Buffalo, Erie Co., NY, USA) married William Henry FARR (7 May 1859 born Hamilton, Ontario, Canada - 17 Mar 1934 Buffalo, Erie Co., NY, USA).

Would love to learn whom she was an Indentured Servant to and where they came from in hopes to learn who her parents where?

Comment: +1 Fantastic question, and welcome to GFH! Thanks for the details you have provided thus far. Do you have any documentation or other records that you have discovered to this point? If you can share those here it would help keep people from reporting results you have already discovered...

Comment: Since you don't have her marriage, what source have you used for Elizabeth/Eliza/Lilla's maiden surname?  That's the most important bit of information to get correct, to find her before the marriage, when she may have been a servant.

Comment: Court records may help, if she ever filed a complaint against those who she was indentured to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if [this](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-267-12129-254054-71?cc=1529100&wc=10936236) is the right person, but an on the 1892 NY State census in Buffalo shows an Eliza Galloway, servant, age 28. She is living with the Murphy family. Of course she is probably the wrong person: your's was born in Scotland.